# GPS cordinates does not passed to Emulator

Tags: android, gps

I tried passing GPS coordinates by DDMS manualy and GPX as well. Nothing works @ my end. Always shows 'poor GPS availability'. From Debug I see that GPS is enabled.
Thanks.

```
public class SurroundgpsActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//For GPS
Timer timer = null;
TimerTask scanTask = null;

private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;
private Button BtnGpsCoord=null;

private String gpsFolder = "/sdcard/assignment1/gps1/";

//MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);    
//mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BtnGpsCoord=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    BtnGpsCoord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View V) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting GPS...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Handler handler=new Handler();
            timer =new Timer();

            scanTask = new TimerTask(){

                public void run() 
                {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            getGpsAutomatically();
                            System.out.println("Calling getGpsAutomatically");
                        }
                   });
                }
            };
            // setting the timer of 10 minutes
               timer.schedule(scanTask, 300, 600000);
            }
        });
    }

private void getGpsAutomatically()
{   
    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    System.out.println("\nisGpsEnabled:"+isGpsEnabled);

    if (isGpsEnabled == false)
    {
        String err_msg = "GPS is disabled, Kindly enable it.";
        showGPSError(err_msg);                  
    }
    else
    {   
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        //String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);    
        String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000L, 500.0f, this);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        System.out.println("\nLocation:"+location);
        try 
        {               
            printGpsLocation(location);     
        }       
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
private void printGpsLocation(Location location)  throws IOException
{       
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    if (location != null)
    {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        String destination ="latitude = "+lat+";longitude = "+lng;
        fOut = openFileOutput(gpsFolder + "location.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        osw.write(destination);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        fOut.close();               

        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        location.reset();      
    }
    else
    {   
        String err_msg = "GPS is working poorly.";
        showGPSError(err_msg);  
    }
}

private void showGPSError(String errorMsg)
{       
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
    alertDialog.setMessage(errorMsg);
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {               
            return;
        }
    });     
    alertDialog.show();
}           

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000L, 500.0f, this);      
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{       
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Did you set the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission in the manifest (among the other permissions like ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).

Comment: try to understand GPS is for location for device and its cant work in emulator

Comment: Yes, the emulator can emulate the GPS. But you have to pass the locations (the coordinates) via the adb (or use Eclipse). For the application to accept these coordinates the application needs the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks. I add ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION  but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, go to Window->Open Perspective->DDMS, then type one in Location Controls and hit Send.